# QgsComposerArrow

Tags: qgis-plugins

```
>>> QgsComposerShape
<class 'qgis.core.QgsComposerShape'>
>>> QgsComposerLabel
<class 'qgis.core.QgsComposerLabel'>
>>> QgsComposerLegend
<class 'qgis.core.QgsComposerLegend'>
>>> QgsComposerMap
<class 'qgis.core.QgsComposerMap'>
>>> QgsComposerPicture
<class 'qgis.core.QgsComposerPicture'>
>>> QgsComposerScaleBar
<class 'qgis.core.QgsComposerScaleBar'>
**>>> QgsComposerArrow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'QgsComposerArrow' is not defined**
```

I need to create a line in composer window from plugin. But there is no definition.

Comment: It might be that the SIP definition is missing for some reason. You may get a better response on the qgis-dev mailing list.